# "look forward in" or "look forward to"?

Tags: idioms

> We are *looking forward* **in** knowing you, helping you achieve the best oral health ever.

Why did they put 'in' here instead of 'to'?

Comment: Where did you see this? Would you put a link to the source?

Comment: @Cardinal https://www.goodmanko.com/what-sets-us-apart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason they used “in” instead of “to” appears to be nothing more than that their English isn’t very strong. There are multiple problems throughout the text in that page, including a number of outright grammar errors, several typos, and a range of what I’d consider to be style problems.

The bottom line is that the phrase “...looking forward in...” is simply an error, nothing more. It should be “...looking forward to...” (or perhaps “...look forward to...” as @virolino suggests).

(Still; given the genuine effort they appear to have made, they do look like a nice bunch of dentists!)

Answer (score 1):

The [**idiom**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/look-forward-to-sth) has a fixed structure:

> [subject] **looks(s) forward to [verb]-ing** + [rest of sentence]

Examples:

> - I **look forward to hearing** from you.
> - Jane **looks forward to dancing** at the ball.

Any other from is not idiomatic.

Note that the original sentence also uses present continuous:

> We **are looking** forward

which should actually be present simple - especially because it is a formal communication.